# Need some assistance with an issue i'm facing with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i've had a recent project upgraded from a 2021 LTS version to a 2022 LTS and ran into some few Library errors when the project was open which interfered with taking builds.So i had to switch back to the earlier version (2021) and when i did, it showed some "Library/Bee/Artifacts" error. So i closed the Project and cleared the entire Library folder and opened it again. Now this time, the console was clear but when i tried to Play, it showed an error saying "Compiler errors need to be fixed" even when there was none listed.

So i removed the Unity Hub along with the Unity versions and re installed the 2021 LTS version and the latest 2022 LTS available. Same problem persists in all projects and also in New Empty projects.

Anyone know what the issue might be and how to fix this?

-Cleared Library.
-Removed and Reinstalled.

Comment: Could you use a bit more descriptive title? Currently it seems there is not much we can do from our side without having your actual project in front of us ...